# Batch -"access is denied" when accessing a text file using batch

Tags: batch-file, editing

I have been having problems with making  a batch script that can write into a old text file. When i try to run it with the old text file it says that "access is denied" (so when i try to put any text into the existing file)

Anyways here is the code:

```
@echo off
title file editor/creator
set lineNR=0
:start
set /p ANS= Do you want to access a 1:"old file" or 2"create a new" [1/2] 

if %ANS% EQU 1 ( goto old
) ELSE if %ANS% EQU 2 ( goto new
) ElSE ( echo invalid input & goto start)
:old
set /p name = what is the name of the file 
set /p ending = what type of file is it 
goto loop
:new
set /p name= what do you want the name of the file to be 
set /p ending= what type of file do you want the file to be 
echo %name%.%ending%
:Q1
set /p echo_off= do you want echo to be off? [y/n] 
if %echo_off% EQU y ( 
echo @echo off >%name%.%ending%
goto loop
) ELSE IF %echo_off% EQU n (
goto loop
) ELSE (
goto Q1
)
:loop
echo press CTRL+LSHIF+C to end loop
goto loop1
:loop1
set /a lineNR=%lineNR% + 1
set /p line= %lineNR%: 
echo %line% >>%name%.%ending%
// this is where it says that access is denied
goto loop1
```

Comment: `set a = b` makes a variable named `a `(Note the space!) with a value of ` b`(Note the space!). Remove the spaces between the equal sign

Comment: Also see [this MS support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/250494/-access-is-denied-error-message-appears-when-permissions-are-correct) for more information on your issues

Comment: Thanks this worked ;3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a simple, but a common issue.

---

```
set a = b
```

Creates a variable named `a` (with the space) and a value of  `b`(with the space).

Remove the spaces and it will work.